# Script to get the Gitlab User details like "last_activity_on" into an excel sheet

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

We have around 10k users in GitLab. We need to prepare an excel sheet that contains the user details like last activity, last sign, created, active or inactive, etc.

These are the details we need to capture in the excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this we will use the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#for-admins

```
GET /users
```

In order to get the info you describe you need to use the following script with an `admin access token`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Username,Email,State,Created At,Last sign in at, last activity on" > user_activity.csv
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <admin_access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/users | jq '.[]' | jq "select ((.web_url | contains(\"bot\") | not))" | jq '"\(.username) \(.email) \(.state) \(.created_at) \(.last_sign_in_at) \(.last_activity_on)"' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' | sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g' >> user_activity.csv
ssconvert user_activity.csv user_activity.xls
```

The output is `user_activity.xls`